# Perl поочередное выполнение

Tags: perl

Есть cron-скрипт, на котором выполняется функция

`Generate(17, "test",3,1 , int(rand(3)+1));`

Последний аргумент это рандомное число, которое уже и передается в саму функцию. Как записать аргумент так, чтобы передавалось поочередно число от единицы до трех, каждый раз, когда этот скрипт выполняется на кроне?

Comment: сохраняйте где то последнее число (конфиг, системные переменные) и проблема уйдет сама собой.

Answer (score 1):

Вы где-то должны сохранить каунтер, а в функцию передавать остаток деления на 3:

```
my $counter =  read_from_config()
Generate(17, "test",3,1 , $counter%3 +1);
save_to_config( ++$counter );
```

т.к остатки деления на 3 могут быть: 0, 1, 2, - то мы должны тут прибавить 1, чтобы получить ваши требуемые: 1, 2, 3

Comment: Зачем же так сложно, если можно просто сохранять последнее число, как предложил KoVadim, без делений/прибавлений?

Comment: @МАН69К: Нужно передавать числа `от 1 до 3`. Вы `if`ами логику предлагаете делать?